# ¿Se puede añadir ceros a la derecha con VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Dispongo que una base de datos en `Access` en la cual, con `Visual Basic for Applications` ya hay creados unos formularios que realizan diversas acciones.

En uno de los formularios se ha creado un botón para realizar un método que rellena un archivo `XML`.

El archivo `XML` se debe validar después de rellenarlo, y uno de los elementos lo relleno con números. Algunas veces, de la base de datos estos números vienen con decimales "10.22" y otras veces no.

Los números deben quedar con decimales ya que si no el `XML` no se valida correctamente.

He intentado lo siguiente, pero si el número es "18" el resultado es el mismo, no se añaden ceros:

```vb
CDbl(numero)
```

```vb
CDbl(CInt(z.campoBD(7)))
```

¿Existe alguna manera de añadir ceros a la derecha? o ¿se puede formatear de alguna manera?

Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

No sé como tienes los datos, pero al usar `CInt` lo estás convirtiendo en entero, así que pierdes cualquier decimal que hubiera.

Al usar `CDbl` lo conviertes en Doble, que sí admite decimales, pero si el número introducido no tiene, los ignora. Tienes que adaptar el formato

Si en VBA pones `Debug.Print Format(18, "0.00")`, siempre te devolverá `18,00` (mi separador decimal es la coma, si el tuyo es el punto, lo devolverá con punto).

Prueba a ver si de esa manera te sirve.

Otra cosa que influya puede ser cómo estás guardando los datos en el propio campo. Como no has puesto ejemplo, solo puedo aventurar, pero quizás guardándolos como tipo Currency o Decimal te pueda servir.

Un saludo.